# Two Elliptic Curve Points having the Same X coordinate

Tags: elliptic-curves, collision-resistance

Suppose in a elliptic curve (say the curve equation is: $y^2 = x^3 -17$) with prime order $q$, we have $(x,y_1) = nP$, where $P$ is a generator and $n<\lceil{q/2}\rceil$. Can we claim that there does not exist $n' < \lceil{q/2}\rceil$, such that $(x,y_2)=n'P$ is a valid curve point where $y_2 \neq y_1$?

Comment: For [Dr. Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock), answer to question as worded in [revision 6](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/96275/6) is still **No**. If $(x,y_1) = nP$, where $P$ is a generator and $n<\lceil q/2\rceil$, then $n'=n-2\,(n\bmod q)$ also verifies $n'<\lceil q/2\rceil$, and $(x,y_2)=n'P$ is a valid curve point where $y_2\neq y_1$. The catch is that the question allows negative $n'$ and $n$. The [accepted answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96286/555) correctly restricts $n$ and $n'$ to be positive, making Yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Fix the $x$ co-ordinate and let $c=x^3-17$. The equation $y^2\equiv c\pmod p$ has at most two solutions (it will have zero if $c$ is a quadratic non-residue, two if $c$ is a quadratic residue and one if $c\equiv 0\pmod p$). If it has two solutions $y_1$, $y_2$ they will be additive inverses: $y_1\equiv -y_2\pmod p$. In the standard formulation of the elliptic curve group (taking the point at infinity as the identity), two points are inverses of each other on the curve if and only if they have the same $x$ coordinate and $y$ coordinates additive inverses. This means that $(x,y_1)+(x,y_2)=\mathcal O$. We rewrite this as $nP+n'P=(n+n')P=\mathcal O$ and conclude that $n+n'\equiv 0\pmod q$. This tells us that $n'\mod q=q-n$. We now note that $0<n<\lceil q/2\rceil\iff q>q-n>\lceil q/2\rceil$.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we claim that if $n < \lceil{q/2}\rceil$, then there do not exist $y_2 \neq y_1$ such that $(x,y_2)$ is a valid curve point?

No, such a claim would be false.  If $(x, y_1)$ is a valid point, that is, if $y_1^2 = x^3 - 17$, then $(x, q-y_1)$ is also a valid point.  Hence, unless $y_1 = 0$, there will always be a second point with the same $x$ coordinate.

Comment: I'm not certain whether the question is intended to be whether or not there exists $(x,y_2)=n'P$ with $n'<\lceil q/2\rceil$. In this case there is not such a solution as $(x,y_2)$ will be equal to $(q-n)P$ and $q-n>\lceil q/2\rceil$.

Comment: Ah, the dilemma: answering the question asked, or what the OP wanted to ask?

Comment: @Daniel S yes that is what I meant, edited the question. How can we show that $(q-n)P = (x,y_2)$ when $nP=(x,y_1)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $P = (x,y)$ has order $q$, then $$(q-1)P = -P = (x,-y).$$
When $q=2$ (equivalently, $y=0$), these two points coincide: $P=-P$.